# Comparisons with boolean values in Python

Tags: python, variables, memory, boolean

I have seen it said that, in Python, comparisons with boolean values should be of the form `if x:`, not `if x == True:`, and certainly not of the form `if x is True:`.

```
>>> 
>>> id(True)
505509720
>>> a = True
>>> id(a)
505509720
>>> random_string_to_reference_a_different_area_of_memory = "Python"
>>> id(True)
505509720
>>>
```

Playing around with variables and looking at memory locations (see above), it looks to me like there is only one `True` and one `False` object, so why shouldn't we do `if x is True:` (or is it actually fine to do so)?

Also, is there any reason why we shouldn't do `if x == True`, other than the fact that the `== True` is unnecessary; if so, would you be able to give me a description in terms of memory?

I personally feel that using `is` is more appropriate than using `==`, since when we are doing a comparison it looks like we are actually looking at whether a variable points to the `True` or `False` object. Could anyone give me an explanation of what is best, and why, and how it all works?

Comment: Presumably when you say you've *"seen it said"*, you mean https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations? Also, *"how it all works"* is rather too broad for an SO question.

Comment: Just because the id of `True` and `False` *appear* to be consistent, doesn't mean they're guaranteed to be so.

Comment: FYI, looking at two object ids without those objects being alive at the same time is kind of pointless. The old one could have been garbage-collected, resulting in the new one re-using its memory location.

Comment: @MarkRansom It makes sense for them to be though. I shall see if I can find an answer on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using `== True` or `== False` either, unless you *explicitly* need to test against the boolean value (which you almost never don't). The preferred way to perform boolean tests in Python is `if foo` and `if not foo`.

However, from a technical point of view, there's nothing wrong with using `is True` and `is False`. In [PEP 285](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) (which defined the bool type):

> The values False and True will be singletons, like None.  Because
>   the type has two values, perhaps these should be called
>   "doubletons"?  The real implementation will not allow other
>   instances of bool to be created.

So whenever you use `True` or `False` you end up with the same instance.

Comment: Is this just a shorthand introduced into the language for `is` or `==`?

Comment: I didn't know that the language specifically defined `True` and `False` as singletons. +1 just for that.

Comment: Actually it's a different thing. `x is True` tests if `x` is actually the same thing as `True`, so only an actual `True` will satisfy this test. `x == True` would also accept `x` being an instance of a class containing e.g. `__eq__(self, other): return True`. And if you just test for `x` or `not x` all you check is if the value is "truthy" or "falsy" - and empty collections are falsy for example.

Comment: I see. Hence why `1 == True` is `True`, but `1 is True` is `False` (as 1 is "truthy" but is not the same as the singleton `True` (is not stored in the same memory location)). But I am correct in thinking that `if x:` is exactly the same thing as `if x == True:`, am I not?

Comment: You are not. `if x` tests for truthiness. For example, `x = [0]` would be truthy but not `== True`. The reason why `1 == True` is true is that `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True` has the value `1` (`False` has the value `0`)

Answer (score 2):

One reason that you don't do `x is <True/False>` or `x == <True/False>` is that you *aren't always testing for `True` or `False`*. Take the following code:

```
user_input = raw_input(' > ')
if user_input:
    ...
```

This will not work correctly if you do `user_input is True` or `user_input == True`, neither of which will ever evaluate truth-y. There are plenty of other examples where [truth-y and false-y objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) should be as acceptable as `True` and `False` themselves, and e.g.

```
if bool(user_input) is True:
```

is rather less readable.